# How to pin a specific column in a list for SharePoint online modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience

I'm using SharePoint Online modern experience.

Is it possible to fix a particular column not to be scrolled when scrolling horizontally in a list?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the feature of pinning first column in list view is in development & it will be released to SharePoint with future updates.

Here are few details about the feature:

> As you scroll left and right, the first column of your list remains in place; similar to the sticky header that is already a part of Lists.

**Reference**: [Microsoft Lists: sticky first column - built on SharePoint](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?&filters=SharePoint&searchterms=64168)

---

**Additional**:

Currently this feature is already available in **Quick Edit** mode of lists & libraries.

**Reference**: [SharePoint lists and libraries: Sticky column in Quick Edit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?&filters=SharePoint&searchterms=64866)